# I am trying to select value from drop down , but i can't why?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question is i want to select the drop down "Country " "United States"
![This is the one drop down ][1]
This the url : http://www.autodesk.com/resellers/locate-a-reseller?cntr=US
Below is my code,when i run this code it trough's an Exception's

1.Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

2.Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element:

```
public class Autodesk {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.autodesk.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Find a reseller")).click();
       // above steps are pass
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // I AM FACING THE PROBLEM FROM THIS STEP**("CLICKING ON COUNTRY AND SELECT THE UNITED STATES")**
        driver.findElement(By.className("styled_select_small")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("    //*[@id=j_id0:j_id21:reAssignCountryList']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Select Industries')]")).click();

        //Drop down 
        List<WebElement> Country = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_id0:j_id21:reAssignCountryList']//option"));
        System.out.println(Country.size());
        for(int i=0;i<Country.size();i++){
        System.out.println(Country.get(i).getText());
        String CountryName = Country.get(i).getText();
        if(CountryName.equals("United States")){
        Country.get(i).click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please switch to iframe with the following tag:

```
<iframe id="resellerFrame" style="height: 1300px; width: 100%; border: medium none; "  
 scrolling="auto" src="http://autodesk.force.com/plocator?cntr=US&amp;"></iframe>
```

You can use the following statment:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("resellerFrame")));
```

Comment: Hi Rishi Actually I AM FACING THE PROBLEM FROM THE STEP**("CLICKING ON COUNTRY AND SELECT THE UNITED STATES")**                           The country Xpath is //*[@id=j_id0:j_id21:reAssignCountryList']  and  Class name is styled_select_small. pls help me to move forward. THANK U

Comment: Could you please add the below line in your code driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("resellerFrame"))); i.e above the comment //Drop down  and rerun the programme

Comment: Thank U Mr.Rishi. I got it. I try to vote up,but my 
Reputation is less.